# C++, pass down an already defined Struct from on Class to another

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, struct

First of all here is my Code:

parent_class.h:

```
 #include <string>

  class class_parent
  {
  public:   
   struct newStruct
   {
    std::string message;
   };
   void function_of_parent();
    class_parent();
   ~class_parent();
  private:
    int y = 1;
  protected:
    int x = 0;
   };
```

parent_class.cpp:

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "class_parent.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

void class_parent::function_of_parent()
{   
  x = y*10;

  newStruct messageStruct_one =
  {
    "Some text, "
  };
  newStruct messageStruct_two =
  {
    " even more text "
  };
  newStruct messageStruct_three =
  {
    " ...foo"
  };

  std::cout << " Parent Class says: " << messageStruct_one.message   << " "   << messageStruct_two.message << " " << messageStruct_three.message << std::endl;
  std::cout << " " << x << "\n\t" << std::endl;
}
```

class_child.h:

```
  #include "class_parent.h"

  class class_child: public class_parent
  {
  public:    
     void function_of_child();  
     class_child();
     ~class_child();
  };
```

class_child.cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "class_child.h"
    #include "class_parent.h"
    #include <iostream>

    void class_child::function_of_child()
    {
       function_of_parent();     

       std::cout << " Child Class says: " << messageStruct_one.message                                    //here I want to use messageStruct_[one-three] 
                 << " " <<  messageStruct_two.message << " " << messageStruct_three.message << std::endl;  //which was defined in the parent class       
      std::cout << " " << x << "\n\t" << std::endl;
    }
```

When I want to compile it, it says, that messageStruct_[one-three] is undefined, which was to be expected. I know that structs are similar to classes but I still couldn't find a way to use messageStruct_ from the parent_class_function, which is what I want. Using newStruct to make messageStruct_ in the child class works fine, but I'd like to use the one from the parent class. Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `class_parent.h`header as well please?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want? `newStruct` is a type, you can use it in parent and child classes. `messageStruct...` are local variables to the function (as you seem to be aware of). If you define them as class members you can access them too. Is this what you want? Your description is very vague.

Comment: Your code is declaring the newStruct structs locally within the parent function. This is why your child class does not have those three structs defined. Scope is the problem.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor I already tried it out with defining them in public, I just wanted to try if I could get it more overseeable by putting them in functions, but I already had the idea it wouldn't work... Just wanted to find a way to make it neat. But appearently putting them into public is the only Option...

Answer (score 0):

Your structs in the parent function are defined locally. They will not be available outside the scope of the function. If you want your parent function to be the one creating these structs then you could have some method to create and return your structs. Like so

```
newStruct class_parent::create_new_struct(std::string text)
{   
    struct newStruct result;
    result.message = text;
    return result;
}
```

Then call it in your child like so

```
messageStruct_one = create_new_struct("some text");
```

Comment: Buut could I define them in public, then edit messageStruct_one.message in class_parent_function and then pass it down to the child class?   Edit: dumb question, of Course it worked...

Answer (score 0):

The variables `messageStruct_one`, `messageStruct_two`, and `messageStruct_three` are local to the method `class_parent::function_of_parent`.

If you want them to be visible to another method, you would need to define them as `protected` members of the parent class.

```
  class class_parent
  {
    public:   
      struct newStruct
      {
        std::string message;
      };
      void function_of_parent();
      class_parent();
      ~class_parent();
    private:
      int y = 1;
    protected:
      int x = 0;
      newStruct messageStruct_one =  { "Some text, " };
      newStruct messageStruct_two =  { " even more text " };
      newStruct messageStruct_three =  { " ...foo" };
  };
```

Comment: Okay, that is something I have already tried out and it worked, I only wanted to try if it possible to maybe do it this way (what I wrote in the question. I just wanted to have it more neatly arranged). But could I edit messageStruct_one.message in the function and then pass it down to the child class?  Edit: dumb question, of Course it worked...